# Is there always a smooth variant of a homeomorphism between smooth manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, inverse

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth homeomorphic manifolds. Let $h:M\rightarrow N$ a homeomorphism.

Does there exist $r:M\rightarrow N$ that is still a homeomorphism and additionaly smooth? Can it be chosen in way that retains a certain similarity to the homeomorphism? Analogously, does there exist a smooth homeomorphism $\ell:N\rightarrow M$ that is similar to $h^{-1}$?

I do not demand that the maps are $r$ and $\ell$ are equal, which would not be possible always. Neither I demand them to be diffeomorphisms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think one can perburb $h$ is make it a smooth map and it is still onto. Not sure if you can get a one to one map.

Comment: If I understood well, the exotic sphere is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere

Comment: This, I think, can be done always if h is PL (this is surely true for Milnor's exotic spheres). In general, I am almost sure that this is impossible. Proving something like this would be tricky, the 4-dimensional E8 manifold is probably the best candidate. Here is the reason: One can probably prove that such smooth homeomorphism has to be quasiconformal. (Since the singular set of its inverse has measure zero.) Then one can apply Donaldson-Sullivan.

Comment: What I wrote is partially wrong since a smooth homeomorphism need not be quasiconformal, but maybe the method used byDonaldson and Sullivan goes through in the setting of smooth homeomorphisms.